# How to avoid code repetition in patterns?

Tags: macros, pattern-matching, racket

If I have a pattern like `(structure-type-name field1-pattern (app some-function pattern-with-variables-a-b) (app some-function pattern-with-variables-c-d))`, what can I use instead of repeating much code for the 2 latter fields to still have `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` bound? Alternatively, I'd also be satisfied with 2 bound variables containing the lists `` `(,a ,c) `` and `` `(,b ,d) ``, respectively.

### EDIT

```
#lang racket

(struct my-struct (field1 field2 field3) #:transparent)

(define s (my-struct '(3 4) '(6 5) '(7 8)))

(match s [(my-struct `(,x ,y)
                    (app (curryr sort <) `(,lo1 ,hi1))
                    (app (curryr sort <) `(,lo2 ,hi2)))
          (- (* x lo1 lo2) (* y hi1 hi2) (expt lo1 hi2))])

(match s [(app struct->vector
               (vector 'struct:my-struct p (app (curryr sort <) `(,lo ,hi)) ...))
; The following line is long and the computation artificial, but just for the sake of an example.
; However, imagine my-struct having more fields.
          (apply - `(,@(map (curry apply *) (map cons p `(,lo ,hi))) ,(expt (car lo) (cadr hi))))])

(match s [(app (compose vector->list struct->vector)
               (list 'struct:my-struct p (app (curryr sort <) `(,lo ,hi)) ...))
          (apply - `(,@(map (curry apply *) (map cons p `(,lo ,hi))) ,(expt (car lo) (cadr hi))))])

(require racket/struct) ; provides struct->list

(match s [(? my-struct?
             (app struct->list
                  (list p (app (curryr sort <) `(,lo ,hi)) ...)))
          (apply - `(,@(map (curry apply *) (map cons p `(,lo ,hi))) ,(expt (car lo) (cadr hi))))])
```

Comment: I came up with a solution using an additional `app` with `struct->vector` (or `struct->list`, though curiously DrRacket doesn't make it available by default, despite being in the same section of the Racket reference) and then `(vector 'struct:structure-type-name field1-pattern (app some-function pattern-with-variables-a-b) ...)`. But that's verbose. I suppose there are better ways.

Comment: Maybe with quasiquotation? Or a macro (preferably defined locally, akin to an anonymous function with `lambda`, but on syntax)?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example? What do you want it to look like? What does the code look like currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`define-match-expander`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._define-match-expander%29%29), like this:

```
#lang racket

(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-match-expander sorted-list
  (syntax-parser
    [(_ x ...) #'(app (curryr sort <) (list x ...))]))

(struct my-struct (field1 field2 field3) #:transparent)

(define s (my-struct '(3 4) '(6 5) '(7 8)))

(match s
  [(my-struct (list x y) (sorted-list lo1 hi1) (sorted-list lo2 hi2))
   (- (* x lo1 lo2) (* y hi1 hi2) (expt lo1 hi2))])
```

If your `match` has multiple branches, and you want to skip branches where `sorted-list` doesn't match a list, you also need to add a guard:

```
#lang racket

(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-match-expander sorted-list
  (syntax-parser
    [(_ x ...)
     #'(? list? 
          (app (curryr sort <) (list x ...)))]))

(struct my-struct (field1 field2 field3) #:transparent)

(define s (my-struct '(3 4) 1 2))

(match s
  [(my-struct (list x y) (sorted-list lo1 hi1) (sorted-list lo2 hi2))
   (- (* x lo1 lo2) (* y hi1 hi2) (expt lo1 hi2))]
  [(my-struct (list x y) a b)
   (list x y a b)])
```

---

EDITED: here's another example for how to reduce the repetitive pattern even further, at the cost of being far less general. Here, I assume that every field after the first field wants the "sorted-list" treatment.

```
#lang racket

(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(struct my-struct (field1 field2 field3) #:transparent)

(define-match-expander my-struct*
  (syntax-parser
    [(_ x y (a ...) ...)
     #'(my-struct
        (list x y)
        (app (curryr sort <) (list a ...)) ...)]))

(define s (my-struct '(3 4) '(6 5) '(7 8)))

(match s
  [(my-struct* x y (lo1 hi1) (lo2 hi2))
   (- (* x lo1 lo2) (* y hi1 hi2) (expt lo1 hi2))])
```

The problem for me is that I do not know what is the level of abstraction that you want, and I do not know the shape of your structure. E.g., are the lists always have length two? If so, it might even make sense to have a pattern that looks like `(my-struct* x y lo1 hi1 lo2 hi2)`. But if not, that would not work.

In any case, I don't mean to provide code that you can readily use. I simply give you examples so that you can adapt them to suit your own need.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! It demonstrates that the repeated part can be reduced to a single invocation of `sorted-list`. I'd rather accept an answer showing how to eliminate the repetition completely, and that without introducing much verbosity, as specifically requested in the question, but if none such appears soon, it's going to be yours.

Comment: I gave another example above.

Comment: Great! Although I might end up using something else, your edited answer does fully satisfy all the stated requirements and gives good insight into what's possible with match expanders for which use cases like this seem adequate.